# RIP- Counting to infnity

Tags: networking, routes, router

I'm having problems understanding the count to infinity for RIP.

I understand how the table is initially set up using distance vectors. But when a link breaks the costs must be recalculated and updated in the new table. I'm not sure how the (3,3) value is updated after the (4,1). Why would the cost from node 3 to node 3 be 3.

In this example the prof posted the link between node 3 and 4 breaks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The table is the route table for node 4 as the destination.

(x,y) in the table means "I can get to node 4 via x in y steps.

before the break:
N1 can get to N4 via N2 in 3 steps.
N2 can get to N4 via N3 in 2 steps.
N3 can get to N4 via N4 in 1 step.

After the break, N3 no longer knows how to get to N4 directly. The problem is that N2 *thinks* it knows how to get to N4 in 2 steps, and communicates this to N3. Therefore N3 now thinks that it can get to N4 via N2 in 3 steps, and then the downward spiral begins.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I disagree with the given answer in the question itself (i'm not referring to wookie919 answer".
In real life implementation, there will not be any count to infinity event for the above topology, when link between 3 and 4 is down. Node 3 will know it and it will do a route poisoning where it will inform Node 2 that the link 3<-->4 is down (cost is 16 infinity) and no longer reachable. Node 2 will wait for some time to accept this info.  There is definitely no count to infinity.

Count to infinity only happen in where there is a loop topology in the network
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~curci/itl/labs/countinf/countinf.htm